# Take the event owner informations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a question about FQL query.

I can not take the Owner information of an event:
I get this error:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#602) owner is not a member of the event table.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 602
  }
```

For example for this query:

```
    SELECT name,description, owner.id from event 
    WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() 
    AND start_time > '2013-02-23T00:20:00')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens exactly because `owner` is not a member of the `event` table. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event

But you can use field `creator` to find creator of the event, thus, your query will become

```
SELECT name,description, creator from event 
WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() 
AND start_time > '2013-02-23T00:20:00')
```